# Passar variável de AJAX para php

Tags: php, javascript

Não tenho muita experiencia em Ajax, precisava de uma ajuda. É o seguinte, tenho um formulário que valida a informação com ajax. Agora eu queria inserir estes dados no banco de dados, como posso inserir a variável username na base de dados, por exemplo?

**botão do form**

```
<input onclick="checkForm()" type='button' class="btn btn-info btn-block" value='Inserir' name="submit1">
```

**script.js**

```
function checkForm() {
// Fetching values from all input fields and storing them in variables.
var name = document.getElementById("username1").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password1").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email1").value;
var website = document.getElementById("descricao1").value;
//Check input Fields Should not be blanks.
if (name == '' || password == '' || email == '' || website == '') {
alert("Por favor, preencha todos os campos");
} else {
//Notifying error fields
var username1 = document.getElementById("username");
var password1 = document.getElementById("password");
var email1 = document.getElementById("email");
var descricao1 = document.getElementById("website");
//Check All Values/Informations Filled by User are Valid Or Not.If All   Fields Are invalid Then Generate alert.
if (username1.innerHTML == 'Mais de 4 letras' || password1.innerHTML ==   'Password é pequena de mais' || email1.innerHTML == 'Email inválido' ||   descricao1.innerHTML == 'Descricao inválida') {
alert("Preencha com informação válida.");
} else {
//Submit Form When All values are valid.
//document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
sendData('regista.php', 'POST','username='+username1);
}
}
}



function sendData(url, metodo, dados){
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  alert("Enviado!");
  location.href = location.href;
 }
};
 xhttp.open(metodo, url, true);
 xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xhttp.send(dados);
}



// AJAX code to check input field values when onblur event triggerd.
function validate(field, query) {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Validando..";
} else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

} else {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Error Occurred. <a     href='index.php'>Reload Or Try Again</a> the page.";
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "validation.php?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Envie os dados utilizando o um objeto do tipo XMLHttpRequest. Fiz um exemplo passando apenas o username. Você pode pegar esse dado no php usando `$_POST['username'];`

Segue o exemplo em javascript:

```
function checkForm() {
  var username1 = document.getElementById("username");
  var password1 = document.getElementById("password");
  var email1 = document.getElementById("email");
  var descricao1 = document.getElementById("website");
  if (username1.innerHTML == 'Mais de 4 letras' || password1.innerHTML == 'Password é pequena de mais' || email1.innerHTML == 'Email inválido' ||  descricao1.innerHTML == 'Descricao inválida') {

  alert("Preencha com informação válida.");

  } else {

  //configure aqui seu endereco, o metodo em que quer passar os dados(GET OU POST)
  //e os dados que quer enviar
    sendData('seuendereco/seuscript.php', 'POST','username='+username1);
    //document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

  }
}
function sendData(url, metodo, dados){
 xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      alert("Enviado!");
      location.href = location.href;
    }
 };
 xhttp.open(metodo, url, true);
 xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xhttp.send(dados);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Coloco a função sendData no meu script dps de fechar a função do checkForm?

Comment: exato, e lembra de dentro do checkForm você usar a sendData(), da forma que eu usei.

Comment: coloquei da mesma forma, nao estou a ter qualquer retorno do ficheiro php. No meu ficheiro tenho `<?php 


if (isset($_GET['username'])){
    $user = $_GET['username'];
 echo "$user";
}

?>` Coloquei o codigo completo no post

Comment: Tenta usando $_POST em vez de $_GET. Reparei também que você está  mandando para uma página chamada regista.php, não deveria ser registra.php?

Comment: Claro, tentei, mas também nao resultou. No recebo nada de volta

Comment: Me perdoe esqueci de adicionar a linha que define o Content-Type, editei o código, tente novamente por favor

Comment: continuo sem receber o echo do php, no form o name do username está correto

Comment: Abre o inspecionador de elementos e vai no console, verifica se acusa algum erro por favor

Comment: Um aviso e um erro
`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
2form_script.js:19`   

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`

Comment: O erro está nessa linha: if (username1.innerHTML == 'Mais de 4 letras' || password1.innerHTML ==   'Password é pequena de mais' || email1.innerHTML == 'Email inválido' ||   descricao1.innerHTML == 'Descricao inválida')

Vem no chat

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38304/discussion-between-lf-ziron-and-david-concha).

Answer (score 2):

Usa isso no JS, vai enviar os parâmetros para o teu código PHP onde você pode enviar para o banco de dados.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "seucodigobanco.php",
    data: { 
        usr: username1,
        pws: password1,
        ... //Resto dos parâmetros
    }
})
.done(function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
});
```

Maneira de pegar os parametros no `seucodigobanco.php` seria

```
if (isset($_GET['usr'])){
    $user = $_GET['usr'];
}
if (isset($_GET['pwd'])){
    $pass = $_GET['pwd'];
}
... //Resto dos parâmetros

//Resto do código de persistência no banco de dados em PHP
```

E em seguida o resto do código relativo ao banco de dados no PHP.

Qualquer `echo` que você der no `seucodigobanco.php` vai cair como string na variável `msg` do `.done()`

Não esqueça de adicionar o JQuery ao seu projeto.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ele não está utilizando jquery

Comment: Verdade, não tinha reparado, não sei que ele possui alguma restrição para não usar, já que não citou, mas enfim, vou editar minha resposta falando para adicionar o JQuery